# Which is the probability that the text is of book "A"?

Tags: probability

The word "and" consist $10\%$ of the words of the book "A" and $20\%$ of the words of the book "B".

A text "C" is attributed to $60\%$ to book "A" and $40\%$ to book "B".

If in an arbitrary list of nine words of that text, "and" is found, which is the probability that the text is of book "A"?

$$$$

Could you give me a hint what we have to do?

Let E be the event "there exists the word "and".

Is the probability maybe equal to $$P(A\mid E)=\frac{P(A\cap E)}{P(E)}=\frac{0,60\cdot 0,10}{\frac{1}{9}}\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $E$ occures is we find the word "and" at least once in $9$ trials. This trials can be considered as independent, in other case the problem is unsolvable. So, with probability $0,60$ this $9$ words are from book "A" and with probability $0,40$ this $9$ words come from book "B". If the text comes from book "A", the probability to find "and" is 
$$1-\mathbb P(\text{all 9 words differ from "and"})=1-(1-0,10)^9.$$ 
For the case when all words are from "B", the probability to find "and" among them is $1-(1-0,20)^9$. 
By Law of total probability, 
$$
\mathbb P(E)=0,60\cdot\left(1-(1-0,10)^9\right)+0,40\cdot\left(1-(1-0,20)^9\right).
$$
And the first summand is the numerator $\mathbb P(A\cap E)$.

Comment: I understand! So, we are indeed looking for the probability $P(A\mid E)$, right?

Comment: Right. And this is the fraction $P(A\cap E)/P(E)$, where both probabilities are wroted above.

Comment: Thank you so much!! :-)